# Word for "being happy that someone else is jealous of me"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "when someone else being jealous of you makes you happy".

Comment: The Germans have a word for such a special type of joy. In English, *Looking good is the best revenge*.

Comment: Please supply a sentence showing how you would use this single word.

Comment: *smug* covers some of the territory of the sought-for word, but is perhaps not a very close fit.

Answer (score 1):

**Gloat**

to look at or think about with great or excessive, often smug or malicious, satisfaction

[www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific word in English to describe this emotion. "Schadenfreude" doesn't describe happiness from others' jealousy; it's the pleasure from their misfortune. The feeling you're talking about is more like satisfaction or smugness.